# Android Firebaseui is not retrieving all data

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm doing a feature on my app where users can post notes. I'm doing this using firebase. However, I'm using FirebaseUI to bind the data in firebase to the listview. I'm using the FirebaseListAdapter function to get the data from firebase and populate it in the listview.

I realized that it's not retrieving all the data that should be retrieved. It only returns one item. I'm not sure what's the problem since I followed the tutorial correctly.

Here is the function that suppose to populate the listview using FirebaseUI functions:

```
 public void setNoteListData(String locationKey){
    String accessPoint = FirebaseHelper.LocationNotesUrl + locationKey;
    firebaseNoteRef  = new Firebase(accessPoint);

    noteAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Note>(MainActivity.this, Note.class, R.layout.view_notelist, firebaseNoteRef) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View vi, Note note, int position) {

            Log.v("Discoverify", "Position: " + position );

            ((TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.note_username)).setText(note.getUsername());
           new DownloadImageTask(((ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.note_avatar))).execute(note.getProfileImage());
            ((TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.note_text)).setText(note.getNoteText());

        }
    };
    noteList.setAdapter(noteAdapter);
    UtilsDiscoverify.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(noteList);
}
```

I noticed that it keeps returning only position 0 and it keeps returning that same position about five times.

Please, any help will be appreciated to why this is happening and how to fix it.

EDIT:

This is the JSON structure:

```
{
  "459e0617-2355-495f-a939-76f49db991ae-07032016030827" : {
    "-KFrMApikRhycsaUv0Ja" : {
      "noteText" : "What a really great house you have Reggie :3",
      "profileImage" : "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xat1/v/t1.0-1/p100x100/12933044_1723753131230562_1603099123146527101_n.jpg?oh=c20c1b07ee3ced68d66740c2d0568d3c&oe=5771FFA9",
      "time" : 1461217704,
      "username" : "prodoxx"
    },
    "-KFrNoXFtvBnOY0w8G6Y" : {
      "noteText" : "This is another awesome note.",
      "profileImage" : "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xat1/v/t1.0-1/p100x100/12933044_1723753131230562_1603099123146527101_n.jpg?oh=c20c1b07ee3ced68d66740c2d0568d3c&oe=5771FFA9",
      "time" : 1461218133,
      "username" : "prodoxx"
    }
  }
}
```

The Firebase reference should retrieve all objects of "459e0617-2355-495f-a939-76f49db991ae-07032016030827" however, it only returns the first object.

This is the Android Log as text:

```
04-21 08:46:39.014 21496-21496/com.example.rescobar.discoverify V/Discoverify: Postiion: 0 & text: What a really great house you have Reggie :3
04-21 08:46:39.015 21496-21496/com.example.rescobar.discoverify V/Discoverify: Postiion: 0 & text: What a really great house you have Reggie :3
04-21 08:56:09.821 21496-21511/com.example.rescobar.discoverify W/art: Suspending all threads took: 12.941ms
04-21 09:00:23.127 21496-21511/com.example.rescobar.discoverify I/art: Debugger is no longer active
04-21 09:02:04.221 21496-21511/com.example.rescobar.discoverify W/art: Suspending all threads took: 18.559ms
04-21 09:08:09.609 21496-21511/com.example.rescobar.discoverify W/art: Suspending all threads took: 18.788ms
04-21 09:15:00.657 21496-21511/com.example.rescobar.discoverify W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.901ms
04-21 09:16:24.960 21496-21511/com.example.rescobar.discoverify W/art: Suspending all threads took: 15.641ms
04-21 09:16:36.471 21496-21511/com.example.rescobar.discoverify W/art: Suspending all threads took: 11.794ms
04-21 09:18:08.206 21496-21511/com.example.rescobar.discoverify W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.804ms
04-21 09:21:17.701 21496-21511/com.example.rescobar.discoverify W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.376ms
04-21 09:25:07.235 21496-21511/com.example.rescobar.discoverify W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.770ms
04-21 09:26:19.006 21496-21511/com.example.rescobar.discoverify W/art: Suspending all threads took: 69.351ms
04-21 09:29:05.828 21496-21511/com.example.rescobar.discoverify W/art: Suspending all threads took: 13.015ms
04-21 09:30:21.640 21496-21496/com.example.rescobar.discoverify V/Discoverify: Postiion: 0 & text: What a really great house you have Reggie :3
04-21 09:30:21.650 21496-21496/com.example.rescobar.discoverify V/Discoverify: Postiion: 0 & text: What a really great house you have Reggie :3
04-21 09:30:21.654 21496-21543/com.example.rescobar.discoverify I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-21 09:30:21.727 21496-21496/com.example.rescobar.discoverify V/Discoverify: Postiion: 0 & text: What a really great house you have Reggie :3
```

Comment: Check that FirebaseHelper.LocationNotesUrl + locationKey doesn't actually give you the location of that one item.

Comment: See if it logs "position 0" as many times as there is data in firebase

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Same for the logcat btw. Text beats a picture of said text any day of the week.

Comment: I added the JSON structure and Android log as text but, had a difficult time fomating the Android log.

Comment: Thanks for that. What location does `accessPoint` end up pointing to?